# errror when trying to run rds cli commands

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, centos, aws-cli, amazon-rds

I have the following error when trying to run the rds cli command, I have looked and cannot find anything related which describes why I am getting this error:

```
rds rds-describe-db-instances
rds-describe-db-instances:  Refused: Signature expired: 20160721T013819Z is now earlier than
 20160721T151824Z (20160721T153324Z - 15 min.)
```

I am trying to extract logs from the RDS instance, In the past I was able to extract the logs successfully, The credentials have not changed.

Any idea why I am getting this issue?

Comment: Try updating the time of your server 1. sudo service ntp stop 2. sudo ntpd -gq 2. sudo service ntp start and then try

Comment: Hi I tried the above , managed to stop the service, then ran ...... ntpd -gq   which resulted in    .... ntpd: no servers found. I then started ntpd and ran the ntpd -gq, But i still get the error. I just wanted to point out that the ntp.conf on this server has been modified to allow the puppet agent to be in sync with the master, so instead of using a server such as server 1.centos.pool.ntp.org iburst , I am using the ip of the master like so: server <ip_of_master>  iburst so the two are in sync.

Comment: So it is working now?

Comment: Hi, thank you very much as this was ntp related, I removed the line in the ntp.conf pointing to the master server and put in the standard centos servers, and then restarted the ntpd service which solved the issue.

Comment: Isn't the new syntax :  `aws rds describe-db-instances `

Comment: hi i also had downloaded the rdscli seperately and so the rds commands also worked. But the issue was on both awscli and rdscli.